# Override ABP.IO Login page

Tags: abp

I am using Abp.io .net core template with MVC/Razor model.

I am trying to override just the cshtml of the login page. Followed the documentation at https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface#overriding-a-razor-page-cshtml

I downloaded the login.cshtml template from https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Web/Pages/Account and placed it in my Web project under Pages/Account/Login.cshtml

Build is successfull.

When running, click on login page and below error is shown:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Volo.Abp.Account.Web.Pages.Account.LoginModel' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Any idea what I am missing? I just want to replace the cshtml and not the underlying code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your web module depends on `AbpAccountWebIdentityServerModule` or `AbpAccountWebModule`? (https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web/MyProjectNameWebModule.cs#L50)

- Also, there is a community article about "how to customize login page". You can read it from [here](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd).
- You will see in the article, a new model created and inherited from the `LoginModel`. And it's used as the modal of the **Login.cshtml** file.
- You can examine the source code of the article, from [here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/Authentication-Customization).

Comment: Thank you, that article was excellent. I was missing the model part. Looking at the documentation, i had just modified the cshtml and was trying to inherit the default model of volo.

I do understand this article was for an older version as the newer LoginModel has 3 parameters rather than 2. schemeProvider, accountOptions and identityOptions. When we run the code and click on login after entering credentials, we get the error:

AbpException: Options must be derived from the Volo.Abp.Options.AbpDynamicOptionsManager`1!

Any pointers on this please?

Comment: To answer your first question, it depends on AbpIdentityWebModule