# Login error on ABP OpenId after update to version 5

Tags: c#, identityserver4, abp

I updated an ABP project with OpenId MVC app. This project was on ABP 3.3 and is now on 5.3.

The IdentityServer is on an API (running on port `5001`) with a custom login page. Using the admin client I can login without any trouble. My problem is with a RazorPages client (port `6001`). When I click on login button, I found the following error:

```
ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Volo.Abp.Account.Web.Pages.Account.LoginModel' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

I noted that if I try to access a protected page, I am redirected to my custom login page (on `https://localhost:5001/Account/Login`) and it works fine, but the error is thrown only on login button, that redirects me to `https://localhost:6001/account/login`.

I googled about this error, but can't find anything. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123995/override-abp-io-login-page) is the only one on StackOverflow with the same error message, but isn't my problem (the custom login *page* **is** working, but not the login *button*).
I read the changelogs between versions 3 and 5 and can't find any breaking changes related to login process, too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the urls provided and with a bit of knowledge of the abp framework, it seems you have not overridden the login page, but rather created your own in the mvc project and trying to use it to authenticate.

What you should do is override the login of the identityserver, this way, you will be using the same service but with your own logic/ design.

Please check this tutorial: [How to Customize the Login Page for MVC / Razor Page Applications](https://community.abp.io/posts/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd)